# Invalid Object name when do sql query nested SELECT

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I have a problem which is i can't figured out how to solve the error.

The query is :

```
SELECT 
    token.id, 
    (SELECT * FROM token FOR JSON PATH) [datas] 
FROM 
    PO_token AS token 
JOIN 
    mapping AS map ON token.id = map.id
```

and the error is :

> Invalid object name 'token'.

The 'token' in this error case refer to :

```
SELECT * 
FROM token 
FOR JSON PATH
```

Can I use that table alias in nested select query?

Comment: Think you might need a CTE or something similar here.

Comment: Replace `token` with `PO_token`. You're trying to `SELECT` from an alias, you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks guys for advice, but my question already solved by create temp table

Comment: While you may have avoided this error using a temp table, I'm pretty certain @Larnu is correct here.

Comment: I agree with @scsimon here. Using a temporary table seems like a waste or resources. If I asked you to read from a piece of paper twice, you wouldn't copy the entire contents out, and then read from that copy twice; the copy is a waste of time. That's, effectively, what you've done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - using an alias in a where clause in a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151470/sql-using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause-in-a-subquery)